# What's a really good tactic trainer rating on chess.com for a Candidate Master?

Tags: tactics, rating, training

I'm currently a Class B with a TT rating of 2100. I would like to aim to become a 2100 with norm of Candidate Master. What tactic rating does a CM usually have? How strong are Expert class chess players in tactical calculation?

Comment: With tactical ability of your caliber I think you should focus on other things

Comment: @Jimmy360 What would you recommend that user122965 focus on? (I ask because I'm not a good enough player to suggest anything, but figure that (s)he and/or others might benefit from explicit thoughts on the matter.)

Comment: @CharlesRockafellor I added some information

Comment: I hardly see masters on SE. Might get a good answer from /r/chess.

Comment: I'm 1900 TT on chess.com and my OTB is 1920. So it's surprising your tactics are that good and you aren't higher rated. I agree with others. Work on other things.

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot get to Candidate Master on tactics alone, most Candidate Masters have much higher tactics trainers ratings than you do. For example, Candidate Master Mago has a TT rating of 2602. While you should continue on your TT journey, you should also study master games, endgames, and positional play.